# What is best index to optimize this mongodb aggregate pipeline Query?

Tags: database, mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query, nosql

Tried few indexes but it goes scans all the documents in collection. I just need to keep the scanned docs / return docs ratio under 1000. (this will helps to reduce the atlas alerts mentioning the ratio has exceed the 1000). Also I need to know usage of hint in aggregate query is a good option or not.

```
"pipeline": [
      {
        "$match": {
          "status": {
            "$in": [
              "STATUS"
            ]
          },
          "$and": [
            {
              "pId": {
                "$nin": [
                  null,
                  null
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "bId": {
                "$nin": [
                  null,
                  null
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "dueDate": {
                "$nin": [
                  null,
                  null
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "proposedPaymentDate": {
                "$nin": [
                  null,
                  null
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "amount": {
                "$gt": 0
              }
            }
          ],
          "pInvoiceId": {
            "$exists": false
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "$sort": {
          "pId": 1,
          "amount": -1
        }
      },
      {
        "$lookup": {
          "from": "pcollection",
          "localField": "pId",
          "foreignField": "lId",
          "as": "p"
        }
      },
      {
        "$unwind": {
          "path": "$p"
        }
      },
      {
        "$match": {
          "p.aId": {
            "$in": [
              {
                "$oid": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
              },
              {
                "$oid": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
              },
              {
                "$oid": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
              },
              {
                "$oid": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
              },
              {
                "$oid": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
              },
              {
                "$oid": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "$skip": 400
      },
      {
        "$limit": 400
      }
    ],
```

Comment: What is the purpose of all these `$nin: [ null, null ]` conditions?

Comment: represents the $exists checks

Answer (score 2):

Your condition does not make much sense, you can try this one:

```
[
   {
      "$match": {
         "status": "STATUS",
         "amount": { "$gt": 0 },
         "pInvoiceId": { "$exists": false }
      }
   },
   { "$sort": { "pId": 1, "amount": -1 } },
   {
      "$lookup": {
         "from": "pcollection",
         "localField": "pId",
         "foreignField": "lId",
         pipeline: [
         {
            "$match": {
               "p.aId": {
                  "$in": [
                     { "$oid": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" },
                     { "$oid": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" },
                     { "$oid": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" },
                     { "$oid": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" },
                     { "$oid": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" },
                     { "$oid": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" }
                  ]
               }
            }
         }
         ],
         "as": "p"
      }
   },
   { "$unwind": { "path": "$p" } },
   { "$skip": 400 },
   { "$limit": 400 }
]
```

Then the best index should be `{ status: 1, pInvoiceId: 1, amount: -1, pId: 1 }`

Comment: i think `p.aId` still can be optimized without have to use `$oid` by converting `p.aid` to string ObjectId. `let: { pAid: { "$toString": "$p.aId"}`. the reason is rather then converting all payload one by one iniside `$in`, just convert the source to be `string`.

Comment: @TobokSitanggang we don't have any sample input data, however based on the query I would assume `p.aId` holds an `ObjectId`. An index on `aId` will not be used if you convert query values to string.